# ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number, bind parameter between select and from

Tags: c#, odp.net

When I execute C# script like bellow, its give ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number

```
using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
using (OracleCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
using (OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter())
using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
{
  cmd.BindByName = true;   
  cmd.CommandText = "SELECT :A A FROM DUAL";
  cmd.Parameters.Add("A", "THE DATA");
  da.SelectCommand = cmd;    
  da.Fill(dt);
}
```

but when I change cmd.CommandText = "SELECT :A A FROM DUAL"; to cmd.CommandText = "SELECT 'A' A FROM DUAL where :A = 'THE DATA'";
it's run

My question, is **bind params** between **select** and **from** can't be executed by C#?

> SOLUTION :  I've changed the library from Oracle.DataAccess to
> Oracle.ManagedDataAccess

Comment: `SELECT :A A FROM DUAL` What are you trying to achieve by that query?

Comment: No, I get that. But what is it trying **to do**? Let's say the parameter was `"Bob"`. What do you expect the query to return? If `DUAL` has 20 rows, you want to return 20 rows all with a single column called A with the value of `"Bob"`? Is that what you are trying to achieve? Or is `"Bob"` a column name? Or something else?

Comment: example, if there 20 "Bob", and concatenate with rownumber, i want to get "Bob 1", "Bob 2", ... "Bob 20"

but, that was not the main reason, I want to create db query manager with c#, I have toad, and toad can execute the script

Comment: I change Oracle.DataAccess library to Oracle.ManagedDataAccess library and it fixed

Answer (score 0):

I change Oracle.DataAccess library to Oracle.ManagedDataAccess library and it's works

Answer (score -1):

Invalid character is `:` because SQL cannot recognize it in select statement so do it as following

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT A FROM DUAL WHERE A = @A";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@A", "THE DATA");
```

`Updates`

Oracle commands need to `:` in parameter like `where A=:A` and not selecting your columns like `select :A A from`

To answer your question, error come from SQL query and not from C#

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oracleclient.oraclecommand.commandtype?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @mjwills Orcale commands need to `:` in parameter like `where A=:A` and not selecting your columns like `select : A  A from`

Comment: That isn't what your answer says. Your answer says to use `@A`. **That will not work**.